# Kubuntu 20.04 (kernel 5.0.4) doesn't recognize Kobo Aura anymore

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, ebooks

I'm having problems with my ebook reader Kobo Aura (first version).
I updated my e-reader to the last version of the firmware (4.25.15875, 9/11/2020), also the kernel of Kubuntu 20.04 is updated: this is the output of "uname -a"

```
Linux zotnam 5.4.0-54-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 10:37:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I disabled tlp to see if it could interfere, but nothing changed. The ebook reader is not recognised even if I launch the command "lsusb".

I had no problems before the updates.

Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Have you cold rebooted the Kobo Aura?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.

I plugged into a different machine (a Raspberry Pi4, 5.4.83) and it worked fine.

My guess is that the USB hardware or drivers on the Kobo are a bit problematic.